# How To Avoid NullPointerException in JasperReports Data Source

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jasper-reports, datasource

I have a *datasource* tag inside a *subreport* in my **.jrxml** file.

Sometimes the datasource object is `null`, and that makes JasperReports throw a `NullPointerException`.

How can I avoid this exception?

I have the following code in my .jrxml file:

```
<subreport runToBottom="true">
    <dataSourceExpression>
        <![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{someListOfObjects})]]>
    </dataSourceExpression>
</subreport>
```

I got `NullPointerException` in cases when `someListOfObjects == null`

Comment: Did you try something like this: `<![CDATA[$P{someListOfObjects} == null ?
 new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource() : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{someListOfObjects})]]>`?

Comment: @AlexK, Yeah, I did - unfortunately, when I do that, the studio doesn't even compile it.

Comment: Looks strange. It is a valid expression. What error did you get?

Comment: Strangely enough, no error shows up on the console. The resulting .jasper file just doesn't appear.